# Functions that share errors and sealed traits

Tags: scala, error-handling

I'm implementing a library for kadmin commands. With, amongst other things, the following methods:

```
def changePassword(principal: String, newPassword: String): Either[ErrorCase, Boolean]
def deletePrincipal(principal: String): Either[ErrorCase, Boolean]
```

These two operations might return an error, so their return type is `Either[ErrorCase, Boolean]`. Where `ErrorCase` is defined as:

```
trait ErrorCase
case object InsufficientPermissions extends ErrorCase
case object PrincipalDoesNotExist extends ErrorCase
case object IncorrectPassword extends ErrorCase
case object PasswordTooShort extends ErrorCase
case object PasswordWithoutEnoughCharacterClasses extends ErrorCase
case object PasswordIsBeingReused extends ErrorCase
case object PasswordExpired extends ErrorCase
case object UnknownError extends ErrorCase
```

My problem is: if I define the trait ErrorCase to be a sealed trait, I will be putting a burden on the user of the API to check all the possible `ErrorCase`s when he/she invokes one of the API methods. This makes sense for the  `changePassword` method, because all of these error cases might happen in this operation. But for the `deletePrincipal` method this makes no sense since all the error cases related with passwords will never happen. In other words, the API methods share error cases, but every method does not necessarily use every error case.

How can I make the trait sealed but somehow specify that in each of the methods only some of the ErrorCases will be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Any problem in computer science can be solved with another level of
>   indirection, except the problem of too many levels of indirection.

```
sealed trait ErrorCase
sealed trait PasswordErrors extends ErrorCase
sealed trait OtherErrors extends ErrorCase

case object IncorrectPassword extends PasswordErrors
case object PasswordTooShort extends PasswordErrors
case object PasswordWithoutEnoughCharacterClasses extends PasswordErrors
case object PasswordIsBeingReused extends PasswordErrors
case object PasswordExpired extends PasswordErrors

case object InsufficientPermissions extends OtherErrors
case object PrincipalDoesNotExist extends OtherErrors
case object UnknownError extends OtherErrors
```

Not sure what's the best way to handle the `UnknownError` (subclass of `OtherErrors`, or of `ErrorCase` directly, or something else), but it's up to you to figure this out.

Comment: note that you can say `case object SomeError extends PasswordErrors with OtherErrors` if you want to have an error that is common to more than one operation.

Comment: Although this solution works it does not scale for more methods. I would have to build up a very complex hierarchy of objects in order to accommodate all the possible cases.

Comment: If you want to stay on the type-safe side, you don't have the choice but introduce types. I don't see any other way to introduce types, maybe with the exception of using `shapeless` or macros. But that would be a totally different story, at least in terms of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

> I will be putting a burden on the user of the API to check all the possible ErrorCases when he/she invokes one of the API methods

Why? They can just match on `_` to handle all error cases at once.

```
deletePrincipal("me") match {
  case Right(bool)                 => ???
  case Left(PrincipalDoesNotExist) => ??? 
  case _                           => ???
}
```

The only problem I see is if you're providing a catamorphism for `ErrorCase` (i.e. a `fold` method). But then again, a `fold` with 8 parameters is pretty awful anyway.